# Convert bitwise operation (i & 1) from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, bitwise-operators

I have the following code in C++ from a book/tutorial on OpenGL:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        droplet_x_offset[i] = random_float() * 2.0f - 1.0f;
        droplet_rot_speed[i] = (random_float() + 0.5f) * ((i & 1) ? -3.0f : 3.0f);
        droplet_fall_speed[i] = random_float() + 0.2f;
    }
```

Now I have tried to convert it to Java, and mostly it is trivial:

```
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        dropletXSpeed[i] = random.nextFloat() * 2.0f - 1.0f;
        dropletRotSpeed[i] = (random.nextFloat() + 0.5f) * ((i & 1) ? -3.0f : 3.0f);
        dropletFallSpeed[i] = random.nextFloat() + 0.2f;
    }
```

Except that `((i & 1) ? -3.0f : 3.0)` is not accepted by Java with the message:
 *incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean*.

Can someone explain me what (`i & 1`) exactly does and how should it be replaced in Java?

Comment: `&` is the bitwise and operator.

Comment: @ZouZou I know what it is. But what is `i & 1` doing? And @Downvoter, **explain** please.

Comment: i & 1 wont return boolean 1 & 1 = 1

Comment: It will give you the value (either 0 or 1) of the bit at position 0 of  of `i`. If you take `i = 2` (`10` in binary), applying this mask will give `(10 & 1) = 0`

Comment: In c/c++ iguess if(1){} is valid but in java if(true){} is valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C/C++, in Java conditionals have to evaluate to a boolean.

For example:

```
int i = 1;
if (i) { ... }
```

isn't valid in java.

Your ternary would need to be:

```
(i & 1) != 0 ? -3.0f : 3.0f;
```

Comment: @peter.petrov No, you're right ... it's what I get for not writing C for 4 years.

Comment: i & 1 is either 1 (if i odd) or 0 (if i is even). Right? ;) OK

Comment: To be clear, I think my original would have been fine *for this case* but the proper equivalency with C evaluation is `!= 0`. Non-zero values in C equate to `true`

Answer (score 1):

Using a trigraph is not as efficient as a formula for simple cases.  This is because a branch miss is so expensive.  You can do the same like this.

```
(3 - 6 * (i & 1))
```

This will be 3 if `i` is even and -3 if it is odd.

Note: as you have a loop there is an even simpler solution.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i += 2) {
    dropletXSpeed[i] = random.nextFloat() * 2.0f - 1.0f;
    dropletXSpeed[i+1] = random.nextFloat() * 2.0f - 1.0f;
    dropletRotSpeed[i] = (random.nextFloat() + 0.5f) * 3.0f;
    dropletRotSpeed[i+1] = (random.nextFloat() + 0.5f) * -3.0f;
    dropletFallSpeed[i] = random.nextFloat() + 0.2f;
    dropletFallSpeed[i+1] = random.nextFloat() + 0.2f;
}
```

BTW nextFloat() is reasonably expensive.  If you don't need 24-bit of randomness you can try something like this.

```
public float next8bitFloat() {
    return random.nextInt(256) * (1.0 / 256);
}
```